# Create array of same value in Amibroker

Tags: trading, amibroker

I would like to create an array of same value in Amibroker. The array should look like this;

```
Arr_fix[0] = 80;
Arr_fix[1] = 80;
Arr_fix[2] = 80;
...
Arr_fix[n] = 80; //n is LAST_VALUE of array
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply write

```
var = 80;

Plot( var, "var", colorDefault, styleLine );
```

and "80" will be there on entire array length of a symbol.

On the other hand if you want to create a custom array then do

```
n = ...; // rownum value

mat = Matrix( n, 1 );

for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    mat[i][0] = 80;

printf( MxToString( mat ) );
```

or shorter

```
mat = Matrix( n, 1, 80 );
```

n could be Barcount too.

You could also convert from string to matrix:

```
matstring = "[80;80;80;80]";

mat = MxFromString( matstring );

printf( MxToString( mat ) );
```

In order to convert Matrix block(s) to 1-dim array use **MxGetBlock** function.

Check AFL function reference ti get details of each function
http://www.amibroker.com/guide/AFL.html